# Find what page was active before currently active one (Windows Store App)

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

How can I find what was the previous active page in my Windows Store App project?

For example, I have PageX that somewhere inside it I do a:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageY), document);
```

Then on PageY, "OnNavigatedTo" method I want to know what was the previous active page ( PageX in this case )

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you could populate a data structure that represents the navigation history by point-cutting in correspondence of the loading of (navigation to) a page.

You could factor such a behavior into your custom base page class.

Alternatively, you could extend the provided NavigationHelper class and provide such a behavior into hook methods such as onNavigatedTo().